# How to use tomcat native(version 8.5.x) to serve static file upload and download?

Tags: java, tomcat

I means how to use in coding, not how to setup and config tomcat native, which is best practices?

Comment: Do nothing. Tomcat already supports this with the default servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring [this project](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/)?

The link I've mentioned explains the configuration pretty well, so I don't think I can add something there. Its just a set of instructions you should follow depending on OS you're running.

In a nutshell you can build it and add to the tomcat startup configuration file the path to the native library and then its transparent to your application.

Now, there is nothing to be done "in coding" as you ask, it doesn't expose any java APIs for the programmer of the business application that runs in WAR in tomcat. Its purely a tomcat system thing. If it doesn't exist at all, everything will still work.